# Generatin finger print template

Tags: windows-ce, smartcard, fingerprint, moc

I need to generate finger print template on Windows CE 5.0 device.
It has izzix finger print reader.
I have to MOC (Match on card). My smart card has template derived from my finger print.
I can read finger print using reader. But how can i generate template that will be sent to card for verify.
I don't have any izzix document.
Are there any sample or suggestion?
thanx.

Comment: it is Bitel Flex 7000 terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Every fingerprint reader I've used (admittedly it's only 4, but that's a pretty good sampling considering the number out there) has their own SDK for generating and matching templates.  It's not something that you can just put together with your own algorithm.  I highly recommend contacting [the fingerprint reader OEM](http://www.digent.com/English/product/algorithm.htm) or the device OEM and asking them how it should be done.

Comment: I could not find any SDK download link or any SDK document. Where can i download SDK?